# What would be a good game making engine supporting Vector images?

Tags: camera, html5, flash, vector-art

I want to create a simple platforming game, in which you are a square in a wonderful world. I would like this game to be able to be played in browsers. Basically I am searching for something similar to "Flixel", but with the following features:

- Support Vector Graphics
- Allow zooming/rotating objects without producing huge amounts of lag as soon as you are using more objects. (Because I want to rotate the map around the player) So in other words, preferably zoom the viewport/camera instead of the objects themselves.

Does an engine like that exist?

Comment: Are you looking for an engine that supports specific vector schemas? (i.e. .SVG, .AI etc)

Comment: Not neccesarily, but SVG would be useful.

Comment: It isn't an engine, but OpenVG is a hardware accelerated api that is available on a lot of mobile devices and some desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Flash is vector based (and their vector renderer is really fast). Since you tagged your question with flash, I guess you're looking for something that's more of a game-engine?

Flixel and Flashpunk are both bitmap based engines. The only other engine that's commonly used would be the [Pushbutton](https://github.com/PushButtonLabs/PushButtonEngine) engine. Sadly the development on this engine has stopped.

In my opinion the feature-set of flash alone is plenty enough to start developing games. No need for a specialized game-engine. Also there are lots of 3rd party libraries available that can add some missing feature to the existing flash API. Have a look at this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-libraries-do-you-use-for-developing-games-in-actionscript).

**Update:** If you'd rather venture into developing games with JavaScript/HTML5, [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) might be for you. These are "just" libraries to render vector-graphics, not game-engines though.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to make the game with vector images? Once your screen gets filled with a lot them, it's going to slow down considerably.

That being said, have you tried with the Citrus Engine? http://citrusengine.com 
I'm not sure if it covers yous specific needs, but it's specifically made for platform games

Cheers!

edit: I forgot to mention that is open source now! :)

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like citrus engine!

Comment: lol, I just saw three questions that were talking about plaformers and the same answer applied to all of them! :D